# Cloud firestore does not wait until returned promise finished

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Im not sure if I get the right idea with cloud function, especially the firestore part.

As the below code snippet have shown, Im listening on a write to a specific document and trying to update other document at the same time. Once all of them are done, the client side will retrieve all the testProducts. But once retrieve completed, the latest info of '2222' is not downloaded and still displayed with the old data. I have noticed three weird outcomes.

1. It seems like the function does not wait until the returned promise is completed. the testProduct refetch happens before the promise is finished. Not sure if thats just how firestore function works.
2. if I return null in the function, the data of 111 still gets updated.I seems like the onWrite doesn't really care whats running inside the body?
3. Im also trying to return a result('status 200') from the server, but obviously client side gets nothing.

Appreciate any help on this.

```
exports.updateProduct = functions.firestore.document('testProducts/1111').onWrite((change, context) => {
  const newValue = change.after.data();
  return admin.firestore().doc('testProducts/2222').update({
    description: newValue.name
  }).then((value) =>{
    console.log('Hello World');
    return 'status 200';
  });
});
```

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how Cloud Functions background triggers (including Firestore triggers) work.  They do not "return" data to the client.  They just take actions in response to changes that match your trigger definition.  If you need to return data to a client, use an HTTP trigger instead.

Comment: Does that means the update request to doc 1111 has actually finished and returned to client, and this firestore function is just catching the change and provide a chance to do something extra?

Comment: Functions only trigger AFTER a change is made.  They do not intercept anything to alter its outcome.

Comment: You save my day, thanks @DougStevenson

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work, but the `testProducts/2222` document shall already exist in the DB. The doc for the [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update) method says that:

> The update will fail if applied to a document that does not exist.

You would trigger the Cloud Function by creating, modifying or deleting the `testProducts/1111` document, see the doc here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events.

> `onWrite`: Triggered when `onCreate`, `onUpdate` or `onDelete` is
>   triggered.

---

However, you could modify your code a little bit in such a way you return the promise returned by the asynchronous [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update) method, instead of a value.

```
exports.updateProduct =  functions.firestore.document('testProducts/1111').onWrite((change, context) => {
  const newValue = change.after.data();
  return admin.firestore().doc('testProducts/2222').update({
    description: newValue.name
  })
});
```

Note that with a Cloud Function triggered in the background with the `onWrite()` trigger, the client is not supposed to receive any response: the process happens in the background. So `'status 200'` is never returned to the client and if you don't issue a new query to the database "the latest info of `'2222'` is not downloaded".

If you want a response on the client side, you could either:

1. Set up a listener with the [`onSnapshot()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) method, in order to listen for change to the `testProducts/2222` document. With a listener "the latest info of `'2222'`" **will be automatically** "downloaded", to re-use your words.
2. Use an [HTTP Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) or a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) that you trigger from the client and that sends back a response.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. yeah, The testProducts/2222 does exist in the firestore. I guess my key question is more like when the client trying to update doc 1111, does the client side wait for the above firestore function to be finished? Or does it just not care and complete immediately, and then this function gots triggered to do some thing extra?

Comment: Actually the client side has, by default, no idea about what the background triggered Cloud Function is doing. The background triggered Cloud Function is triggered when something is written in doc 1111. It can be written from the Firebase console, by another Cloud Function or from the client, it does not make any difference.

Comment: @Panda World Hi, did you have the time to look at the proposed solution?